# Justifying solutions of damped harmonic differential equation

Tags: derivatives

Let us have a damped harmonic pendulum differential equation $m \ddot{y}+\lambda \dot{y}+{\omega^2}y=0$,
 where $\dot{y}$ is differentiation over $t$.

I would really value your help to check that $y=A(e^{-kt})\cdot \sin(\omega t)$ is a solution.

I try to substitute $y$ for a solution and check the equality, but something goes wrong when I differentiate.

$(mA(w^2(-e^{kt})\sin(wt)+k^2e^{kt}\sin(wt)+2kwe^{kt}\cos(wt)))+\left(λA\left(e^{kt}k\sin \left(wt\right)+\cos \left(wt\right)\omega e^{kt}\right)\right)+\left(Ae^{kt}w^2\sin \left(wt\right)\right)=0$

$0=(-mA{w^2}e^{-kt}+mAk^2e^{kt}+λAke^{kt}+Aw^2e^{kt})\sin(wt)+(2mAkwe^{kt}+λAwe^{-kt})\cos(wt)$

Comment: Did you compute $y'$ and $y''$ ? If not, do it and replace.

Comment: Group sines and cosines and set coefficients equal to $0$. This would be give relations between parameters.

Comment: Any further ideas on the next step? Thankyou @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: Is there a relationship between $k, m,$ and $\lambda$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us start $$y=A e^{-k t} \sin (t \omega )$$ $$y'=A e^{-k t} (\omega  \cos (t \omega )-k \sin (t \omega ))$$ $$y''=A e^{-k t} ((k^2-\omega^2 )  \sin (t \omega )-2 k \omega  \cos (t \omega ))$$ Replace in the equation $$my''+\lambda y'+\omega^2y=0$$ Forgetting the $A e^{-k t}$ common factor, you then have
$$\sin (t \omega ) \left(k^2 m-\lambda  k-(m-1) \omega ^2\right)+\omega  (\lambda -2    k m) \cos (t \omega )=0$$ SInce this has to be true for all $t$, you have $$\lambda -2    k m=0 \tag 1$$ $$k^2 m-\lambda  k-(m-1) \omega ^2=0 \tag 2$$ So, from $(1)$ $$k=\frac \lambda {2m}\tag 3$$ Plug in $(2)$ to get another condition between $\lambda$, $\omega$ and $m$.